# Pass a variable from an apex:inputText to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputtext

in my Vf page I have an apex:inputText:

```
<div Class="OtherVendor">      
    <apex:outputPanel id="otherPanel">
        <div Class="Other">
            <apex:inputText id="othervendor" value="{!otherVendor}" rendered="{!vendor=='Other'}">   
            <b> Other: </b>
            </apex:inputText>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>  
    </div>
```

In my controller I need to use the variable *"othervendor"* inside one of controller's method. I had defined:

```
public String otherVendor{get; set;}//Vendor Name
```

But when I use it inside the method, the variable is null and is not equal to the inserted Text. The method:

```
public void createProducts(){
System.debug('vendor '+ vendor);
System.debug('othervendor '+ otherVendor); //just to spect the value
}
```

In which cases this could happen? How could I solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Can you post the action/command button you are using to call method?

Comment: I solved while I was writing I have an idea and IU solved the problem. The problem, as you guessed, was in the command button. I don't know how mark this as solved?

Comment: Post the answer yourself  and accept :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and it works:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="otherPanel">


<div Class="Other">
        <apex:inputText id="othervendor" value="{!otherVendor}" rendered="{!vendor=='Other'}">   
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="import"  action="{!specifyVendor}"/>
        <b> Other: </b>
        </apex:inputText>
    </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

action:

```
public PageReference specifyVendor(){
    System.debug('specifyVendor');    
    displaySelectedText  = vendor;
    System.debug(vendor);
    System.debug(otherVendor); 
    return null; 
    }
```

`specyfyVendor` let me spect in the debug the variable's value.